# ValidationGroup issue - without group: `DoPostBackWithOptions`, with group: `__dopostback`

Tags: webforms, validationgroup

Validation works fine until I make use of ValidationGroup. Afterward the form submits but no validation occurs. This is the href on the LinkButton before and after I use the ValidationGroup.

Before: `javascript:DoPostBackWithOptions(...)`

After: `javascript:__doPostback(...)`

The `CausesValidation` property is set to true. Why does adding the ValidationGroup change the postback code like that?

Comment: Are you using a updatepanel here?

Comment: Yes but I have tried it with and without the UpdatePanel

Comment: So your question is why the validator wont be triggered or the generated js'DoPostBackWithOptions' is beyond your expectations.

Comment: Primarily, my question is why isn't the validator being triggered. But the reason the validator isn't being triggered is because the produced js changes from `DoPostBackWithOptions` to `__doPostback` whenever I make use of `ValidationGroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the validationgroup on the button, the button should only trigger the matched group validator.

ASP.Net generates WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is because there is a group validator on your page matching with your button's attribute ‘validationGroup’.

Your link button markup code should be similar like that:

```
    <input type="submit" name="btnGroup1" value="Group1" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
new WebForm_PostBackOptions('btnGroup1', '', true,'Group1','', false, false))" id="btnGroup1" />
```

Through debugging the js code, you should be able to find there is a js function used to find group validator. This function will validate if 'Group1' validator is there.

Debug this js method see if it can find your specified group validator.

```
IsValidationGroupMatch
```

[image]